# How to get pytest to ask before running a test case?

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following Django management script which tries to run through all of my test cases where, for each test case, the user is given the option to run or not run that specific case. I'm using the `reuse-db` option as you'll see. The problem with this is that the `pytest` tries to add the prefix `test_` to the database name each time `pytest.main()` is called. So, on the second calling, I see this error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "test_test_vgmdash" does not exist

I don't get this error in the first iteration of the loop (and, yes, I choose 'y' for both iterations).

So, I have two questions"

1. Is there a way to get python to ask me whether or not a given TestCase should be run, and repeat that for all test cases?
2. Is there a way for me to use `pytest` discover to get the list of TestCases? I know I could use the introspection library but `pytest` already does this.

Here's the code that's not working quite right:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        all_cases = (
            'TestContractNotifications',
            'TestContracts',
            'TestContractReviews',
            'TestDnD',
            'TestItemImport',
            'TestUnitCalculations',
            'TestAuth',
            'TestAccess',
            'TestDataAnalysis',
            'TestProspectAnalyzer',
            'TestDistReports')

        assert(len(args) <= 1)
        settings.PYTEST = True
        arg_str = "-s --tb=short --maxfail=1 --ipdb --nomigrations"
        choice = raw_input_choices("Reuse test DB?", ['y', 'n'], 'y')
        if choice == 'y':
            arg_str += "--reuse-db "
        if args:
            arg_str += "-k %s" % args[0]
            pytest.main(arg_str)
        else:
            for test_case in all_cases:
                raw_input_choices("Run %s?" % test_case,
                                     ['y', 'n'], 'y')
                if choice == 'y':
                    pytest.main("%s -k %s" % (arg_str, test_case))
```

Comment: There are hooks for [before and after running a suite](https://pytest.org/latest/xunit_setup.html)

Comment: That's a good direction. However, I don't think there's a way to run or not run the function from within the hook. I could see a subclass of TestCase doing this which might not be a bad approach. It seems like there's got to be an easier way though.